# How do I check if value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few select menus that include blank options. When both are blank (usually on the first page load), I would like to show some hidden div.

This is what I have:

```
$('.variant_options select').each(function() { 
    if ($(this).attr('value') === '') {
        // some code here to show hidden div
        console.log("No options chosen");
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to work.

**Edit 1**

For what it's worth, I have tried something like this:

```
if (!$(this).attr('value'))
```

And that has seemed to work, but it breaks functionality elsewhere.

Comment: `if ($(this).val() === '') {`?

Comment: [`if ($(this).prop('value') === '')`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/1048572) or just `if (!this.value)`

Comment: What's with all the downvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<select>` elements don't have a `value` attribute, so you need to use `.val()` on the element to find out if the currently selected option is empty.

```
if ($(this).val() === '') {
    // value of select box is empty
}
```

*`this.value === ''` should also work*

To check whether no options are selected:

```
if (this.selectedIndex == 0) {
    // no option is selected
}
```

Comment: I like where you are going with `this.selectedIndex == -1` but that doesn't work for me. That's actually the functionality I am looking for - if no select box value has been selected, then show some hidden div.

Comment: Or more specifically...on the first page load when it defaults to blank on both select menus, the top solution you have provided here works properly. However, if I chose a value for 1 (or both) of the options, then I go back to blank for both select menus, this no longer works. How can I get it to do this once it has returned to a 'blank' state - even after a value has been selected before? I suspect that this is where your `selectedIndex` value was going...which is why I would love to see more of it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the following:

```
if($(this).val() === '') {
  // value is empty
}
```

I believe also the following too:

```
if(!$(this).prop('value')) { 
  // It's empty 
}
```

Comment: He does use `attr` and it doesn't work. What do you mean by *or*, when to use what?

Comment: @Bergi That was edited in to the question after I answered, I'll update.

Comment: Both of these work for 95% of the cases, i.e. on the first page load when it defaults to blank on both select menus, it does this properly. However, if I chose a value for 1 of the options, then I go back to blank for both select menus, this no longer works. How can I get it to do this once it has returned to a 'blank' state - even after a value has been selected before?

Comment: Hmm.. what 'event' is this wrapped inside? (e.g. click, on etc.) do you have a jsFiddle by any chance?

Comment: Nvm....I got it. Thanks though! I updated Jack's answer to reflect the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$('.variant_options select').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
        // some code here...
    }
});
```

Comment: In case, if you have spaces in options values

Comment: Oh...well I am only interested in the no-value case here...i.e. on the first load of the page, when the select options are blank (or when someone chooses the blank options).

Comment: Yes....that's interesting. A lot more code than just `this.selectedIndex == 0`, but that does achieve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can check for value by using `$(this).val()`

So you would do if ($(this).val === '')`

If you wanted to check for some other attribute, like href or src, you could do

`if ($(this).attr('href') === ''`

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have spaces, use this trick:

```
if ($.trim($(this).val()) === '') { ...
```

Comment: No spaces, because the values are in a pre-defined dropdown menu. I just want to detect if any of the select options have been selected (i.e. if the values are all `undefined` or blank, then the answer should be no and should show some hidden div).